# Characteristic Function of Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability

A characteristic function has the form: $\int_{0}^{\infty}exp[(-it-\lambda)X]*\lambda$.

I have consulted several advanced probability textbook. Durrett just treat i as a real number, which makes the problem quite trivial. However, both Jacob& Protter and Grimmett & Stirzaker state that it is not rigorous to do that, and that you should do contour integral to make a rigorous argument.

I can do it by Taylor expansion or break it into real and imaginary parts.

However, I haven't found a coutour that enable me to do a contour integration in this case...Can anyone show me how to do it?

Comment: Contour integration is unnecessary.  You may view the characteristic function in terms of its real and imaginary parts, for instance, both of which can be evaluated with ordinary (Riemann, real) integrals.